# array initialization in angular 2, Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

when I am initializing array globally (outside the method) its working fine. but when I am initializing the same array inside the method its throwing error unexpected token. you can see into code for location of array. this is array calculateResult[] = [];

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLxSx.png)

```js
private log: string ='result';
private kw: string = 'kw';
private frame: number = 0;
public finalResult[] = [];

//here this array is working fine
calculateResult[] = [];

DisplayResult(){

  //if i initialize this array here, it's throwing error
  // calculateResult[] = [];

  if(some_conditions_true){
     alert();
     this.log = '1SE0 070-2NC70' '\n';
     this.kw = '.37' '\n';
     this.frame = '71' '\n';

     this.calculateResult[0] = this.log;
     this.calculateResult[1] = this.kw;
     this.calculateResult[2] = this.frame;

     this.finalResult.push(this.calculateResult);

     for(i=0;i < this.finalResult.length;i++){
       console.log(this.finalResult[0][0]);
       console.log(this.finalResult[0][1]);
     }
}
```

Comment: What are  '\n' s for? Don't you have compiler error for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first declaration is considered as a class property, so it's correct.

The second one, is incorrect because it is inside the class method and thus should be either declared as

```
let calculateResult=[];
```

if you intend to declare a new array of that name,

either addressed as the class property declared above as

```
this.calculateResult = ...
```

So keep the first one:  `calculateResult = [];`

If you keep it commented, `this.calculateResult[0]` will be undefined in the class method, you cannot refer to it.

Comment: @Faisal guys I tried both let calculateResult=[], let calculateResult [] = []; but I am getting error "14 caused by: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" i think because of  this code.       
      this.calculateResult[0] = this.log;
      this.calculateResult[1] = this.kw;
      this.calculateResult[2] = this.frame; ANY SUGGESTION ?

Comment: Uncomment calculateResult[] = [];, it's the correct one

Comment: You will need to post a new question, with the code and a possible plunker. It will be out of the scope of this question

Comment: just a quick question, I am able to access values in console this way "console.log(this.finalResult[i][0]);" how can i access these 2D values in template.is there any alternative? this way is throwing error {{finalResult[i][0]}} . one Dimension is working {{finalResult[i]}} .

Comment: In which context do you access finalResult[i][0] ? in an ngfor?

Comment: yes in ngFor this is working <tr *ngFor=" let row of rows; let i = index" >
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{finalResult[i]}}</td> .   this 2D not working  {{finalResult[i][0]}}

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize as

```
 DisplayResult(){
    this.calculateResult = [];
 }
```

Comment: thanks now its not throwing error. but it is not updating the array. if I am calling the method again, its not updating the values instead its just append the same values again. any suggestion?